# Proof by induction of recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations

I've been shown the following proof by induction of $P(n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer presumably. This is in the context of algorithmic analysis.

$
P(n):T(n) = 
\begin{cases} 
2T([\frac{n}{2}])+n &,n>1\\
1 &,n=1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow T(n) = n\log_2 n + n
$

Base case, $P(1) :T(1) =1 =1log_2 1+1$

Assume $P(n)$ is true for all $n < m$, show $P(m)$ is true
\begin{align}
\text{LHS } P(m):T(m) &= 2T(\frac{m}{2})+m \\
&= 2(\frac{m}{2}\log_2\frac{m}{2} + \frac{m}{2}) + m \\
&= m\log_2 m + m \\
&= P(m)
\end{align}

I have a few problems with this, firstly it isn't necessary that $n/2$ eventually reaches $1$ so is there even a solution (could this be avoided by changing the condition to $n \leq 1$)?

Secondly the strong induction step seems somewhat dodgy as we are dividing $n$ by $2$ each time so it isn't necessary that the $n/2$ case be covered (5 to 2.5 for example). We could then include all the halves going $(0.5,1,1.5)$ in our steps but then we wouldn't have $0.25$ and so on and kind of misses the point of induction anyway? I'm just a bit confused and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your formula is wrong if $n$ is not a power of 2, you can see this by e.g. calculating $T(3)$. The proof doesn't work, even if you add the Gaussian brackets $[\cdot]$ (rounding up/down), because $2 [m/2] \neq m$ for $m > 1$ not even and $\log_2([m/2]) \neq \log_2(m) - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you write $T(n)=2T\left(\color{red}{[}\frac{n}{2}\color{red}{]}\right)$, I think you misinterpreted either the function `floor` $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$, corresponding to the lower integer part, or the function `ceiling` $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, corresponding to the higher integer part.

You probably didn't make the difference between either of these functions and the square brackets $[\frac{n}{2}]$, which are redundant.

The use of integer part functions solves your problem of distinguishing between even and odd cases - both are rounded (up or down) to an integer.